Visual Studio - Kill all processes created
I have a main process creating small processes.
When I stop debugging, these processes does not kill themselves, preventing any rebuild.
I must go to the windows process manager, search for my processes and kill them each time.
Is there a way to do it with visual studio, either automatically at debug stop or manually ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects

According to my test, Visual Studio itself does not have a built-in module to automatically terminate child processes. In addition, I have also tried using the post-build event command line, which can add commands to terminate specific processes after the project is generated, but it also requires manually adding each process, and there is no way to directly obtain all child process related to the main process. However, if you would like to achieve this effect by using C# program, you can refer to the following:
If you just want to automatically terminate the child process when the main process ends, you can use the ProcessExit event. Here is the official document for reference, as well as the example I created:
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static Process childProcess;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main process started.");

        // Register exit event
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += OnProcessExit;

        // Create a child process
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "notepad.exe",
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

        childProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("Child process started.");

        //Simulate the work of the main process
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main process is running...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Main process finished.");
    }

    // Event triggered when the main process exits
    static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main process exiting. Terminating child process...");
        KillChildProcess();
    }

    // The method for terminating the child process
    static void KillChildProcess()
    {
        if (childProcess != null && !childProcess.HasExited)
        {
            try
            {
                childProcess.Kill();
                Console.WriteLine("Child process terminated.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to terminate child process: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


The pre build event is a better idea than the post build event as i want to clear the processes to allow the build. As i set the same name template to all my processes, i may be able to search them with the event
